# Calling Fetch From React (With Options)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, fetch, auth0

Following [this tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/react/08-calling-apis) I have created an application with servers listening on ports 3000 and 3001.

If I understand correctly, my react application runs on port 3000 and uses the server on port 3001 as a proxy to make api calls to Auth0.

Currently, I can successfully make a fetch request from 3000 to 3001, but the problem is that I am not able to pass in any options.

fetch(url) works without options but I would have to pull variables in from query params.

fetch(url, options) does not work. It will sometimes appear as "status=canceled" in chrome's network tab. Other times (seemingly at random) it shows a 404 instead, and sometimes the request does not even appear in the network tab. In every case, if I pass in options, the api is not called and the log statements placed immediately inside the server's app.get() do not get fired.

I have tried about a hundred different ways to format the options object, but I keep thinking that is the problem. I have also attempted to enable CORS on the 3001 server, but that didn't seem to help.

I would really appreciate any feedback or advice on this. Thanks!

Comment: I suspect your mock server is not setup to run correctly. When you ping the mock server, or do a POSTMAN call, is it returning any data?

Comment: You were right, my server was not setup correctly. I was using app.get() and I guess GET would never have a body in the request.. When I changed it to app.post it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fellow coder from the React support community helped me discover:
1) I was not using event.preventDefault(); and this was causing the status=canceled error

2) My server was set up with app.get() when it needed to be app.post()